# how to obtain ambient noise level in j2me/Blackberry

Tags: audio, blackberry, java-me, signal-processing, noise

I want to measure the noise level and want to increase or decrease volume of device automatically according to surrounding area noise level.

Is it possible? If it is possible then how to get ambient noise level?

Anybody can give me an idea to proceed in right direction?

Comment: You need to decide first whether you want *noise level* or *frequency*, as they are two very different quantities which you will measure in very different ways. Perhaps you could give some background and explain what you are *really* trying to do ?

Comment: Hi Paul thanks to quick response basically just i want to measure the noise level and want to increase or decrease volume of device automatically according to surrounding area noise level.

Comment: OK - you should probably edit out references to "frequency" in your question then, assuming all you want is a measure of ambient noise level.

Comment: OK - I've added some appropriate tags for you too

Comment: The first step would be to find or develop an algorithm to compute the noise level from a digitized audio stream. Once you have that there are samples available that will show you how to digitize audio input.

Answer (score 0):

The **RMS** value of a signal (root mean square) is fast to calculate and is a **standard measure of the overall energy of a signal**.

Tip:
Taking the "noise" signal as the signal from the microphone when the user is listening, not talking (ambient noise). I would not set the volume based solely on the RMS value of the ambient noise signal, but rather set the volume based on the ratio between the RMS of the incoming call, and the RMS of the ambient noise.

```
 Volume = k * RMS(IncomingCallSignal) / RMS(AmbientNoiseSignal)
```